# Substring() in C#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like `VGT501  -  GE TIMES MICROWAVE ELECTRONICS`
and I want to break this string into two part depend on first `-` character .I only want second part of the string for example `GE TIMES MICROWAVE ELECTRONICS`.
I am using  below code:

```
string StaffID = mystring.Substring(mystring.LastIndexOf("-"), mystring.Length );
```

But its giving me `ArgumentOutofRangeException` error.

Comment: The second argument to `Substring` is the length of the desired substring, not an end index.  You can just leave off the second argument if you want to go to the end of the string.

Comment: `string StaffID = mystring.Split(new char[] {'-'}).Last();` maybe?

Comment: @juharr Or [leave it off entirely](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt....`new char[]` is redundant.

Answer (score 3):

The second argument to `string.Substring` is the length of the desired substring.  If you want to go to the end of the string you can use the overload that only takes the starting index.  Also since you want everything after the *first "-" character* you'd actually want to use `IndexOf` instead of `LastIndexOf`.

```
string StaffID = mystring.Substring(mystring.IndexOf('-') + 1);
```

Also it makes more sense to do the `IndexOf` on the `char` and not on a `string` and you need to add 1 so you get everything after the dash.  This also handles the case where there is no dash as `IndexOf` will return -1.  If the dash is the last character in the string you'll end up with an empty string.

If you want to default the value to something other than the original string if the dash isn't found you'd have to do something like the following.

```
int lastDash = mystring.IndexOf("-");
string StaffID = whateverDefaultValueYouWant;
if(lastDash != -1)
    StaffID = mystring.Substring(lastDash);
```

Comment: The classic approach to "return everything after some character, or return everything if the character is not found" is to use `mystring.Substring(mystring.LastIndexOf("-")+1);` because it never throws an exception for a non-null `mystring`.

Comment: Change from `LastIndexOf` to `IndexOf` and you are on target.  An input of `"test - test - test"` would return `"test"` rather than the required `"test - test"`.

Comment: @LarrySmithmier Yeah, based on the _first "-" character_ reference you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
string ss = "VGT501 - GE TIMES MICROWAVE ELECTRONICS";
var result = ss.Split('-')[1];//GE TIMES MICROWAVE ELECTRONICS
//Or  var result = ss.Split('-').Last();
```

By using `Split` you didn't get any error if there is not `-` in your string or if the string is null.

Answer (score 0):

This will pull the string following the first `-` and not error if there is not an instance of `-` in the string or if the initial string is null:

```
string test = "VGT501 - GE TIMES MICROWAVE ELECTRONICS";
var output = (test ?? string.Empty).Substring((test ?? string.Empty).IndexOf('-') + 1).Trim();
```

`output` gets the value: `GE TIMES MICROWAVE ELECTRONICS`

```
string test = "VGT501 GE TIMES MICROWAVE ELECTRONICS";
```

`output` gets the value: `VGT501 GE TIMES MICROWAVE ELECTRONICS`

```
string test = string.Empty;
```

Or:

```
string test = null;
```

`output` gets `string.Empty`